# Why can I not store booleans in a php array?

Tags: php, sql

Why can't I store a boolean in an array? I get an error when I attempt to run it. (On line  line 3)

The columns being retrieved with the exception of stamp are booleans. Here's a snippet of my code.

```
$BoolQ = "SELECT stamp, active, latvian, russianSpeaker FROM tasktable WHERE taskID=usrid;";
$Boolr = mysqli_query($connection,$BoolQ);
$Boolrow = mysqli_fetch_array($Boolr);
```

Error:

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given
```

Comment: The warning is telling you `$Rresponse` is false, nothing to do with storing booleans in array.

Comment: You can't store a boolean in a php array for the same reason you're not reading error message correctly.

Comment: Where does $Rresponse even come from?

Comment: Sorry, mistake when renaming and putting it here. The problem still applies.

Comment: And the reason is the same. Also it won't be the same error, it will be complaining you've passed it a string.

Comment: @JonStirling The Rrespose wasnt the problem, I just renamed the variable when copying it to stack. The error is the same

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array()/mysql\_fetch\_assoc()/mysql\_fetch\_row()/mysql\_num\_rows etc... expects parameter 1 to be resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-mysql-fetch-assoc-mysql-fetch-row-mysql-num-rows-etc)

Comment: @JonStirling I'm using mysqli not mysql, I don't think it's a duplicate.

Comment: @tahibuzij If you follow the link, you'll find it's not limited to mysql_* :)

Comment: It's simple. You're not checking whether your query succeeds. You're **assuming** it will. When it fails, like in your case, instead of a `resource`, you're feeding a `boolean` to `mysqli_fetch_array`. That's what the error tells you - it expected the parameter to be a resource of type `mysqli_result` but you gave it a `false`. Morale of the story: check whether queries succeed. This exact question shows up at least 50 times a day.

Answer (score 0):

In the 3rd line of the code: `$Boolrow = mysqli_fetch_array($BoolQ);` , shouldn't you be using $Boolr as the parameter instead of $BoolQ? If that's a typo, which most probably it is, the result of mysqli_query is false, probably an issue with connection or the query.

Comment: Just a typo, issue is the same

Comment: Thanks. Were you able to fix the issue?

Comment: Not yet, but I have an idea of what could be causing it.